# Count Number of Friday in current month in Laravel using Carbon

Tags: laravel-8, php-carbon

How can I find the number of Friday in the current month? I can use Carbon in my project.

I have used `Carbon::now()->Friday();`
This isn't working.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$now = CarbonImmutable::now();
echo CarbonPeriod::create($now->startOfMonth(), $end->endOfMonth())
  ->filter(static fn ($date) => $date->is('Friday'))
  ->count();
```